# Android Notification to play sound only

Tags: android, audio, notifications

I have a countdown timer in my activity and when it reaches zero I send a notification to the status bar which also plays a custom wav file to alert the user.  I only want the status bar notification to appear if the user isn't using the app at the time but I still want the wav file to play whether the timer app is visible or not.

Is it possible to make the Android notification only play the audio alert?  I've tried using [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) to play the wav file instead but this uses its own volume settings and not the regular notification volume so if your media volume is low then the notification sound plays at a low volume too which I don't want.  I want the sound to play at the same volume as other notifications.

I'm using this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

And supplying the sound like this:

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notifysnd);
```

Comment: Yes it is possible to only play a audio alert.

Comment: Thanks @coder_For_Life22, would you be to show me how?

Answer (score 5):

In 'Adding a sound' section in  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html
there is this note :

> Note: If the defaults field includes DEFAULT_SOUND, then the default sound overrides any sound defined by the sound field.

So, if you want to customize only sound, you may use -

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notifysnd);
notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

Answer (score 4):

According to my experiment, you can indeed send a notification without it appear in the notification area but still have the sound played.

All you need to do is to construct a notification builder and set sound to it, but skip the pending intent, icon, content title and content text.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setSound(your_sound_uri);
notificationManager.notify(1234, builder.build());
```

Comment: These answers are particularly helpful since the docs are wrong about this. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateNotification says, "A Notification object *must* contain the following: A small icon, set by setSmallIcon(); A title, set by setContentTitle(); Detail text, set by setContentText()"

Comment: The icon is required. This causes an error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid notification (no valid small icon)

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

Notification mNotification = new Notification.Builder(this)

            .setContentTitle("New Post!")
            .setContentText("Here's an awesome update for you!")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_lancher)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
```

**three ways to setSound**

```
builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
builder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
builder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
```