# sound for notification

Tags: java, android, audio, notifications

I want to play an mp3 sound when my `Notification` is triggered. For this, I have put an mp3 file in my "res/raw" folder and used the following instruction:

`notification.sound=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/" + R.raw.mySound);`.

But I am getting no sound when the `Notifications` appears!

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put this below code inside the block which will be triggered when notification occurs..

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mySound);
mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);  // Set false if you don't want it to loop
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Works with a collateral problem : the sound level is not controlled by the notification sound level but by the media sound level...

Answer (score 0):

I found an example here -

- [How to play an android notification sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441334/how-to-play-an-android-notification-sound)

This is the code that is used

```
try {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone ring = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        ring.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
```

On the other hand, if you want to customize the sound (as I ausume you do), you should use this code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414495/android-notification-to-play-sound-only/)

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notifysnd);
notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE
```

;

Comment: The second way doesn't work. It shows exactly what I was doing.