# Starting Sound/Alarm when APP Receive GCM Message

Tags: android, alarmmanager, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developing ,for educational purposes, a Android APP.

This APP have a GCMService and works well, but I'm trying to start a simple sound or alarm when the APP receive a certain message from GCM Service.

How I can do this? 
I'm searching for information, but always see the people start a Service or Activity, and I think this is much easy.

Thanks ALL!

Comment: @ypnotize do u want to play a sound on receiving message?

Comment: I now implement gcm messages, but now I'm trying to play a sound around 30secs.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the code into `onMessage()` of `GCMIntentService` like

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_message);
        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
        //Write here for sound notification 
        //for example 
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone ringer = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        ringer.play();
    }
```

---

> start a simple sound or alarm when the APP receive a certain message
>   from GCM Service

You can put condition in above method and play soound. like

```
if ("XYZ".equals(message)) {
//Then Play a sound
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone ringer = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        ringer.play();

}
```

Comment: It's works so good, but I need play a sound ALARM around 30 secs, not the default ringtone (In my telephone now sounds Hangouts ringtone).

How I can modify the sound?
How I can play the sound around 30 secs?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414495/android-notification-to-play-sound-only